# Can I replace a steward in Hearthfire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

Without really thinking about it, I've employed Lydia as my steward in Lakeview; but now I don't have a housecarl in Breezehome anymore. I'd like to fire her and replace her with some other follower and let her head back home.

(I know that I don't *need* a housecarl in every house but it's bugging me that my one house is now "unguarded".)

I can't find any way to have a steward step down or be replaced; there's no dialog option to ask her to resign and I can't seem to ask any other follower to do the job. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you're playing on PC, there's probably a [console code](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) for this. You'll possibly have to spend some time in the Construction Kit and dig through the scripts though...

Comment: Have you tried asking them to follow you then dismissing? Does that just send them back to stewarding or reset them to their original home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**Dismiss Steward**](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/34515/?) mod allows you to dismiss stewards. I admit I haven't tried it yet but if you really want Lydia fired, I recommend making a save, downloading the mod, and giving it a try. Just make sure that you have a save from before you installed the mod just in case something catastrophic happens.

Answer (score 2):

There is but one way and its to slay her, she cant go back to breezehome because her home has been changed to your other house, if you kill her, you can recruit new stewards in after her, but if there is a way to return her there, i dont know of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, kill her and use resurrect on her. Get someone else to be your steward.

Answer (score 1):

The only option to replace a steward is to kill them or disabling them, then bring another follower to your house and ask them to be a steward. The is a mod called **Dismiss Steward Mod** which allows the option to dismiss your steward and get another follower in your house to become a steward. These are the only possible ways to replace a steward if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

**YES!** **It is entirely possible** (if you're playing the PC version).

I had the same problem, so I experimented with some console commands and managed to get Lydia dismissed as my Steward, and made her **return as my housecarl at Breezehome**. Here's how:

1. Take all your valuable items from her, becuase she will lose them after this is done.
2. Kill Lydia
3. Open the console, click her body so she is selected ( her ID is 000a2c94 )
4. Write the following commands in the console, and between each command, close and re-open the console so she has time to reset properly (just as a safety measure).

   - **Disable**
   - **Enable**
   - **Resurrect**

And you're done! You know it's working by talking to her, and she has the original 3 talk options as when she is your housecarl in Breezehome. To really, REALLY make sure it works, travel to breezehome, wait 24 hours, and she will be standing next to her bed as your housecarl once again.

Answer (score 0):

You could just disable her, then whenever, bring her back with  [ player.placeatme XXXXXX ] XXXXX is her coduse her code

Answer (score 0):

Get the Cheat Room mod. Kill her. Revive her. Then hire someone else as your steward. The use the Cheat Spell options that says Reset Actor. Then use Cheat Spell on Lydia. That will send her to Breezehome 
This is mainly helpful for Xbox users but I imagine it would work on PC

Answer (score -2):

If you are using the Better Vampires mod:

Kill the housecarl you made steward
Activate Praestare Sanguinare
Feed on the dead body
Use Tollere Sanguinare

This will resurrect the dead body and turn it back to human.

Answer (score -5):

Yes but only if the previous one has somehow been killed.

Comment: I think it does, but not very clearly and if this says what I think it says, then that was already said in a previous answer.